# Plotly histogram retrieve data associated to x-values after xbins ranging

Tags: python, plotly

I have some data array, it includes prices. I would like to create a histogram, create bins for price ranges, and after that access the data from original dict, ranged in bins.
The array is like this: `[[0, 1, ...], ['aaa', 'bbb', ...], [100, 50, ...]]`, where `array[0]` is numbers, `array[1]` is names, `array[2]` is prices.
So I'm using `array[2]` values for histogram values:

```
fig = px.histogram(x=array[2], labels={'x': 'Price range', 'y': 'Document price'},)
```

After that I apply xbins function to these prices, to sort it in ranges: 0-49, 50-99, etc.:

```
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Price range:' + '%{x}' + '<br>Amount of documents:' + '%{y}' +
                      '<br>Something:' + '{z}',
                      marker={'color': '#2EC7DB',
                              'line': {'width': 1, 'color': 'rgb(25, 25, 25)'},
                              'opacity': 0.75,
                              },
                      xbins=dict(  # bins used for histogram
                                start=0,
                                end=max(prices),
                                size=50)
                      )
```

The result is great. See the resulting picture.

[image: histogram]

Now I want to edit hover text, you can see that I can easily access X and Y values after bin-ranging, it gives me the range and counts as supposed. But I would also like to add all the names (`array[1]`) that were associated to the prices to the hovertext. So is there any way to extract these values (as they are not linked in array, I think should use a dict)? For the bin range 400-449 there are 117 counts, so may I add the names of these values to the hovertext (limiting the total shown amount, e.i. first 30 values)?
Any ideas?

Comment: it's not possible.  if you want bin values use **numpy** `np.histogram()` and generate a plotly bar chart from that (not histogram)